# heroku: local deployment - django static files not deployed

Tags: python, django, heroku

When i deploy locally my static files are not present

my Procfile is `web: gunicorn news_site_prj.wsgi:application`

The console doesn;t any erros with the static files

```
heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
21:46:38 web.1   |  [2017-10-12 21:46:38 +0100] [34267] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
21:46:38 web.1   |  [2017-10-12 21:46:38 +0100] [34267] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (34267)
21:46:38 web.1   |  [2017-10-12 21:46:38 +0100] [34267] [INFO] Using worker: sync
21:46:38 web.1   |  [2017-10-12 21:46:38 +0100] [34270] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 34270
```

The reference to static files in settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "./static"),  # static directory at the project level
)
```

Comment: Try `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` instead of `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "./static")`

Comment: using `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` didn't fix the issue, static files are not being deployed

Comment: Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic` before?

Comment: … and how is your config? `settings.py` for dedicated env? `.env`?